# Parts of object drag when rotating

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting, pose-mode

I'm new to blender and have been fooling around with weight paint and armatures.

Now when i rotate my character, the arms drag while rotating. Not sure how these specific pieces got stuck nor can I edit in pose mode to grab the corner which is stuck.

I'm having a difficult time researching a solution because I'm not sure what is really happening here or what's caused this.

[image: Corner dragging while rotating object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This vertex must be part of an unwanted vertex group. Select it and in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*, on the dropdown menu, click on the *Remove From All Groups* function so that it's not part of any group. Now you can assign it to the group you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! Took me a bit of time to look into this and grasp what you were saying but this fixed it! Appreciate your time.